# Strange results when computing large numbers in python2 then in python3

Tags: python, formatting, cluster-computing

I try to compute  x = (2**83 + 1)/3 which is mathematically an integer and a float in python-x.
In python 2, I get :

```
x = 2**83 + 1
x = 9671406556917033397649409L
```

then

```
y = x/3 = 3223802185639011132549803L
```

In python 3, I get :

```
x = 2**83 + 1
x = 9671406556917033397649409 --> OK
```

then

```
y = x/3 = 3.223802185639011e+24
```

To compare the 2 results, I use a format string instruction in python 3:
`z = '%25d' % y` and I get `z = '3223802185639010953592832'`
and `z = '3223802185639011132549803'` in python 2.
(%i gives the same results, quite normal).
The strange thing is that when I compute 3*Z, I get the good result in python2 and a wrong one in python3.
I can't see where the problem is with my test (computing, formatting, ...).
I'd like to use python 3 and to display `x = (2**83 + 1)/3` with no `'e+24'` but with all numbers.

Does anybody have an idea?

I have to add thet the problem remains the same when using / or // in python2. We get the same result sinc it is mathematically an integer. I should say that the problem is rather with python 3. How can i get the good result (the whole dispaly of (2**83 + 1)/3 in python 3) ?

Comment: In Python3 `/` always returns a float.

Comment: // is for integer division

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for integer division as opposed to the floating point one.

`/` operator returns a floating point number in Python3. To perform integer division in Python3, use `//`.

So, I guess all you need is

```
(2**83 + 1)//3
```

which gives

```
3223802185639011132549803
```

instead of the `(2**83 + 1)/3`.

In Python2.7, both `/` and `//` are effectively the same unless you do something like `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: Thank you but the problem remains the same when using / or // in python2. We get the same result sinc it is mathematically an integer. I should say that the problem is rather with python 3. How can i get the good result (the whole dispaly of (2**83 + 1)/3 in python 3) ?

Comment: @Chichourne What do you mean? I think using `//` instead of `/` would be enough.